# Spliting a string list to floats - memory error

Tags: python, string, split, out-of-memory

I can't handle with splitting a list of strings to a list of floats. I open a text file (.vol, but it just contains text) which last line is an extremely long line of numbers.

> Params1 437288.59375000 102574.20312500 -83.30001831
>   Params2 437871.93750000 104981.40625000 362.10000610
>   Params3 0.00000000
>   Params4 342 1416 262
>   Params5 583.34375000 2407.19995117 445.40002441
>   Params6 20.00000000
>   Params7 1.70000005
>   Params8 126879264
>   Values:
>   0.25564435 0.462439 0.1365 0.1367 26.00000000 (etc., there are millions of values)

Since it's a 10th line of a txt file, I load them into a list by:

```
with open('d:/py/LAS21_test.vol') as f:
txt = []
for line in f:
    txt.append(line)
```

And then I try to convert that from string to floats by:

```
A = []
for vx in txt[9]:
   try:
       A.append(float(vx))
   except ValueError:
       pass
print (A[0:20])
print (txt[9][0:20])
```

This give me that results:

```
[0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 0.0, 4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0]
0.25564435 0.462439
```

What I would like to have is a list of correctly split floats, like:

```
[0.25564435, 0.462439]
```

I used `except ValueError` to omit whitespaces - when using just `float(txt[9])` I get value error.
Second issue: I can't use `txt[9].split` because then I get the 'memory error'.

How can I convert this to a list of floats properly?

Comment: You should add the input file content in order to be easier to understand.

Comment: Just added, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you cannot make txt[9].split() and map it like this: `map(float, txt[9].split())` because the txt[9] is too large.

You can try this generator:

```
def float_generator(txt):
        x = ''
        for c in txt:
            if c != ' ':
                x += c
            else:
                out = float(x)
                x = ''
                yield(out)

for i in float_generator(txt[9]):
        print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here (as mentioned in the comments) is:

1) In the first case you are trying to index into the string before you split it and you are attempting to convert spaces to floats (hence the `ValueError`)

2) In the second case there are probably too many numbers in the list and you are filling up your memory with a huge list of large strings (hence the `MemoryError`).

Try this first:

```
numbers = [float(s) for s in txt[9].split(' ')]
```

This should give you a list of numbers. If this also causes a `MemoryError`, you will have to iterate over the string by hand:

```
numbers = []
numstring = []
for s in txt[9]
    # Reached a space
    if s == ' ':
        numbers.append(float(numstring))
        numstring = []
    else:
        numstring.append(s)
```

This will be much slower but will save on memory.